# How do I set up tabs across the top of the MDI windows in the Jade IDE

Tags: jade-platform

I somehow switched off the tabs option and now I can't remember how to switch them back on.
Anyone know how to make the sub windows in the Jade IDE line up under a tab strip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Options - Preferences - Browser - Mdi - select either "Use Mdi With Tabs" or "Use Tabs Only"